# progress bar in css not smooth

Tags: jquery, css

I am making a timer with a progress bar. It working but it's not smooth as it should be. it begins nice but gradually become slow.

https://jsfiddle.net/vtpe83os/

```
const defaultTiming = 12;
const added = $(window).width() / defaultTiming; 
 let timer = 1;
 let timerInterval = setInterval(function(){
 if(timer  === defaultTiming) {
    timer = 0;
    $("#animate").width(0);
  $("#animate").animate({width: '100%'}, defaultTiming * 1000, function () { $(this).removeAttr('style'); })
 }
 const width = $("#animate").width();
    $("#timer").text(timer);
  timer = timer + 1;
}, 1000);

$("#animate").animate({width: '100%'}, defaultTiming * 1000, function () { $(this).removeAttr('style'); })
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution

You need to add Easing property `"linear"` to animate function.

You were getting slow animation because the default value for easing was `"swing"`

For more info refer docs http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```js
const defaultTiming = 12;
const added = $(window).width() / defaultTiming;
let timer = 1;
let timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (timer === defaultTiming) {
    timer = 0;
    $("#animate").width(0);
    $("#animate").animate({
      width: '100%'
    }, defaultTiming * 1000, "linear", function() {// add easing property "linear", default is "swing"
      $(this).removeAttr('style');
    })
  }
  const width = $("#animate").width();
  $("#timer").text(timer);
  timer = timer + 1;
}, 1000);

$("#animate").animate({
  easing: 'linear',
  width: '100%'
}, defaultTiming * 1000, "linear", function() {// add easing property "linear", default is "swing"
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
}

.chand {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animate"></div>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Consider providing some context. For example, what was wrong with OP's code? What have you changed? Why/how does that resolve the issue?

Comment: In my observation animation speed is still not consistent. It seems fast at beginning and gradually slowing down